# What is the syntax of a Registry key's "Absolute Path"?

Tags: registry, registrykey

Using **Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey** C# functions which require a registry path, like `OpenSubKey()`, using a path like

> @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal
> Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp"

generates an error stating "Absolute path information is required."

What is the syntax to create the absolute path required?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that if there are certain permissions for group "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES" associated with some keys, that access for those applications will be denied with this error code resulting.